# Judicieux remplacement pour « utopique »

Tags: choix-de-mot, néologismes

Lors d'une conversation, un ami m'a dit récemment « Cette idée est utopique ». Il entendait par là qu'elle était idéale mais irréaliste.

Je me suis fait la réflexion que le mot « [utopie](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utopie) », tel que créé par [Thomas More](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_More) dans son roman [*Utopia*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utopia_%28livre%29), était construit d'après des racines grecques signifiant « en aucun lieu » ; *u-* signifiant aucun et *topie* signifiant le lieu (même racine que *topographie*).

J'ai essayé alors de traduire dans ma tête les propos de mon ami : « Cette idée n'est en aucun lieu ». Ça ne veut plus rien dire du tout, puisque cette idée était dans ma tête !

Il existe en tout cas un autre mot construit sur le même modèle qu'*utopie*, c'est [*uchronie*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uchronie), un néologisme du XIXe siècle désignant un lieu hors du temps, généralement un monde parallèle dans lequel notre histoire et la leur se sont séparées à un moment donné. Le [*Steampunk*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steampunk) en est un bon exemple.

Y a-t-il un mot, néologisme, anglicisme ou mot-valise plus à propos que « utopique » pour une idée ?

Comment: L'idée d'un lieu hors du temps, Steampunk et cetera, est plus «anachronique» selon moi.

Comment: Non, anachronique désigne un regroupement de deux éléments qui ne devraient pas exister à une même époque. Charlton Eston qui oublie sa montre en jouant dans Spartacus, ça c'est anachronique. L'uchronie, c'est une époque à laquelle on _aurait pu_ arriver si… quelque chose s'était ou ne s'était pas passé. Et si l'Allemagne avait gagné la seconde guerre mondiale ? Et si les Aztèques avaient envahi l'Europe ? Et si les Égyptiens avaient adoré le dieu du commerce ?

Comment: Oui, je suis d'accord.  J'avais l'intention de dire que le sous-genre Steampunk est, d'habitude, plus anachronique que les autres genres comme d'histoire alternatif, d'histoire câcheé et d'allohistory qui sont régroupés comme «uchronie».

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Idéaliste?  Je m'appuye sur la définition du «Multi-Dictionnaire de la langue française» de Marie-Éva de Villers où c'est défini comme:

**IDÉALISTE** adj. et n.m et f.
1. Qui oriente sa vie vers un idéal élevé qui souvent ne peut être atteint.
2. Utopiste. Des projets idéalistes qui ne tiennent pas compte de la réalité.

SYN. rêveur. En ce sens, le mot a une valeur péjorative.

Answer (score 5):

"C'est une idée poétique", plus sensible que l'utopie dessinatrice de projets irréalistes.

La réponse est bien plus élégante que "Ah! c'est intéressant" (sous entendu, vous continuer à prendre vos pilules?), "dans l'idéal c'est bien mais..." indique une fermeture verrouillée de certitudes plébéiennes.

Certes "l'idée n'est en aucun lieu" réel, car elle ne peut en avoir (dans l'esprit de celui qui formule cette vérité), donc l'attitude de votre interlocuteur semble avoir été négative ( par rapport à l'idée).

"C'est une idée chimérique" (fabuleuse, imaginaire, mythique) correspond plus à l'univers littéraire évoqué, elle peut être discutée.

Les idées utopiques peuvent soulever l'enthousiasme, déclencher des projets, donner des objectifs non réalisables mais positifs.

La beauté du mot utopie réside dans l'espace, le vide (sens oriental) qu'il dégage pour que se révèlent l'humanité, l'univers et ses secrets : n'être autre part que dans son imaginaire pour y construire des rêves, à vous ensuite de connaître la distance qui séparera leurs réalisations de l'utopie.

Answer (score 5):

Il y a un adjectif qui signifie « [qui appartient au domaine du rêve, de l'irréalisable](http://tinyurl.com/se-french-2271-1) » : *utopique*.

Ne pas confondre le sens et l'étymologie. « Utopie » ne signifie pas « qui n'est en aucun lieu ».

Answer (score 2):

Cette expression peut facilement être remplacée par le mot **rêve**.

Comment: Je n'arrive pas à retrouver l'origine des relations que vous avez pu faire entre le rêve, l'utopie et la réponse formatée d'un automate.

Comment: rêve et utopie : cela ne vient pas de la relation directe entre les deux, mais de la question, où il est dit : "« Cette idée est utopique ». Il entendait par là qu'elle était idéale mais irréaliste." ; à partir d'idéal, j'ai eu l'idée du rêve, qui implique souvent l'idée de quelque chose de merveilleux et d'irréaliste. Aucune relation avec l'automate. J'ai dit là quelque chose d'inutile.

Comment: Je trouve évident la relation de proximité entre "rêve" et "utopie".

Comment: @menjaraz la réponse a été modifiée, la référence à l'automate mentionnée dans mon premier commentaire a été supprimée, ce qui le rend incompréhensible et obsolète.